# Правильное написание слов "наряду" и "озеленение"

Tags: орфография

Почему в предложении "На совещаниях в Мэрии, наряду с чисто производственными вопросами, обсуждаются и экономические животрепещущие проблемы, например вопрос озеленения" слова *наряду* и *озеленения* пишутся слитно?

Answer (score 1):

*Наряду* - наречие со сначение "вместе, одновременно". Пишется слитно.
Озеленеие - существительное. Из каких соображений его можно написать раздельно, просто не представляю.

Answer (score 0):

**Предлог** *наряду с* пишется слитно!

Comment: **Предлог** никак не пишется.

Лопатин:
Орфографический словарь
наряду, нареч.

Кузнецов:
Большой толковый словарь
НАРЯДУ, нареч. с кем-чем.

Comment: Я бы понял, скажи вы, что "наряду с" может *использоваться* в функции предлога, но само по себе "наряду" от этого не перестанет быть наречием.